# How Rails render finds variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-5, renderpartial

Simple example:

**index.html.erb:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

I can refactor this and move content to the **_post.html.erb** partial:

**index.html.erb:**

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

**_post.html.erb:**

```
 <%= post.title %>
```

So how Rails passes attributes of every post without creating a block?
My posts_controller index action has only `@posts = Post.all` defined.

I thought that maybe by the name of the partial (post), but looks like its another Rails convention (plural and singular naming). Is it?

Many thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the model name in the collection. The full syntax to render a collection is as follows:

```
<%= render partial: "post", collection: @posts %>
```

However there is a shorthand for this:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

According to docs:

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial. In
>   this case, the partial is _post, and within the _post partial, you can
>   refer to post to get the instance that is being rendered.

You may find detailed explanation in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)